# Forwarding mouse events between GWT panels

Tags: events, gwt, mouse, panel, forwarding

I've got a few GWT panels layered on top of each other inside a LayoutPanel.  My bottom panel requires mouse events, but these are being caught by the top panel.  Is there any way of preventing a panel from sinking events, leaving those events to be caught by a panel lower in the stack?

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the CSS property [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) but that won't work in IE and Opera. For those (at least), I think you'll have to:

1. temporarily hide the higher layers,
2. find the element that would have been targeted in the lower layer (use [`$doc.elementFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from JSNI),
3. and then unhide the higher layers.
4. [fire](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html#fireNativeEvent%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent,%20com.google.gwt.event.shared.HasHandlers%29) a [synthetic event](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#createClickEvent%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) on it

Don't worry, the hide/unhide will be imperceptible to the user (the browser won't even render it)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Is there a convenient method for hiding the layer, or should I remove it from it's parent/add it back in again?

Comment: Also, should I use clientX/clientY or screenX/screenY when calling elementFromPoint? I'm not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Thomas, could you please clarify the last point about `fire a synthetic event`? I have very similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022057/gwt-forward-mouse-wheel-event-to-underlying-element